# Check if date has same day in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Hi there in my app I need to filter some documents through date. I need to see if the first date is the same day of the second date, so I searched on Apple Documentation to see if there are a solution to do this without create a method and I found this instruction [isDate(_:inSameDayAs:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nscalendar/1417649-isdate), but if i try to compare the following date:

`2020-07-29 16:15:50 +0000`

`2020-07-29 22:00:00 +0000`

As you can see the day is the same, but I'm not able to understand why it return `false`, what's wrong?

**CODE**
Here's my code to check the difference between days:

```
myArray.filter({Calendar.current.isDate($0.log.createdDate, inSameDayAs:date)})
```

Comment: Could you show your code? Also, in what timezone are you? Could it be that 22:00 at UTC+0 is another day in your case? If you are UTF+3h for instance.

Comment: I added the code, i live in Italy, but if i convert the date in `Calenda.current` it should be correct or I'm wrong?

Comment: It's just that it's showing using `+0000`, not your "local date", it's 22h in UTC time.. You are currently in GMT+2h, so it's already midnight of the next day.

Comment: Ok how I can fix it?

Comment: It depends where lies the issue. Are your date corrects? Did you meant for instance, the last one being midnight in Italy, or in UTC? That's the first thought. The second one, is do you want to be on the same day in Italy, or in UTC. Depending on that, solution might differs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Date` represents instants in time. Two instants of time could be in the same day in one timezone, but not in the same day in another timezone. These two instants in time:

```
2020-07-29 16:15:50 +0000
2020-07-29 22:00:00 +0000
```

are in the same day in the UTC timezone. However, in a timezone where the offset is 5 hours ahead of UTC (UTC+5) for example, the two times will not be in the same day, because they will become:

```
2020-07-29 21:15:50
2020-07-30 03:00:00
```

in that timezone

Now you should see that the timezone is crucial at determining whether two dates are in the same day.

`Calendar.current` uses the local timezone of the device for almost everything it does. `isDate(_:inSameDayAs:)` is no exception. In your device's timezone, the two dates are not in the same day. However, when you print them out without a formatter, they are always printed in the UTC timezone. In the UTC timezone, they *are* in the same day, making you think `Calendar.current` is wrong. Assuming you actually want to see if the two dates are in the same day in your device's timezone, then `Calendar.current` is right, and you don't need to fix anything.

To print the two dates in your timezone, use a formatter:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = .long
formatter.timeStyle = .long
print(formatter.string(from: yourDate))
```

If you actually want to see if the two dates are in the same UTC day, then you can set the timezone of the `Calendar`:

```
var calendar = Calendar.current
calendar.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")!
// call calendar.isDate(_:_sameDayAs:) rather than using Calendar.current
```

Comment: See the edit. Which timezone do you actually want to use to determine whether two dates are in the same day? @lucgian841

Comment: I will use the italian timezone to determine whether two dates are in the same day

Comment: @lucgian841 Well, then there is nothing to fix then. You just need to realise that those two dates that you think `Calendar.current` is wrong about, are actually not in the same day in Italy.